# How to implement HDP profile for Bluetooth stack with TI?

Tags: android, bluetooth, texas-instruments

i have to transfer ECG eval board data which is from TI to Android Mobile via bluetooth.As for interoperability (HDP) Health Device Profile need to be used.So any one can please help me in finding how to implement HDP on controller side .i mean what documents are required and which are the neccassary steps to be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the examples that came with your android SDK. There is a Bluetooth HDP example there. This should give you a head start. Good luck